# brew install collada-dom issue with mac os 10.9

Tags: macos, dom, homebrew, collada

So I have been trying to install collada-dom and I keep running into this issue not matter what I try.....

```
==> Downloading http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/collada-dom/Collada%20DOM/Collada%20DOM%202.4/collada-dom-2.4.0.tgz
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Patching
patching file CMakeLists.txt
Hunk #1 succeeded at 127 with fuzz 1 (offset 27 lines).
==> cmake . -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local/Cellar/collada-dom/2.4.0 -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=None -DCMAKE_FIND_FRAMEWORK=LAST -DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE=ON -Wno-dev
==> make install
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [dom/libcollada-dom2.4-dp.2.4.0.dylib] Error 1
make[1]: *** [dom/CMakeFiles/collada-dom.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2

READ THIS: https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/troubleshooting
```

brew --config

```
HOMEBREW_VERSION: 0.9.5
ORIGIN: https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew
HEAD: 90cf3ba4583eebb429edf58deea63425fa492718
HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /usr/local
HOMEBREW_CELLAR: /usr/local/Cellar
CPU: 8-core 64-bit sandybridge
OS X: 10.9-x86_64
Xcode: 5.0.2
CLT: 5.0.1.0.1.1382131676
Clang: 5.0 build 500
X11: 2.7.5 => /opt/X11
System Ruby: 1.8.7-358
Perl: /usr/bin/perl
Python: /usr/local/bin/python => /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7
Ruby: /usr/bin/ruby => /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby
```

I'm not sure if the patch ( https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/collada-dom.rb ) fails in 10.9 or it's just a problem with my computer... #help